# Makefile Automatic Target Generation

Tags: macos, bash, makefile

I have the following directory tree

```
moving_files/
        Makefile
        source/
                a
                b
                c
        target/
```

With my Makefile I want to `cp` every file in `source/` to `target/`.
The catch: I want to be able to move other files to `source/` afterwards without having to edit the Makefile. For this purpose I have written this:

```
FILES = $(filter-out Makefile, $(wildcard source/*) ) 
all: $(subst source,target,$(FILES))
$(subst source,target,$(FILES)): $(FILES)
    cat $< >| $@
```

And it works fine.

However, when I execute `touch source/d` afterwards and `make` once again, in addition to `d`, `a`, `b` and `c` get `cat`ed, as well. What do I have to do in order to change this behavior.

Comment: Obviously it is going to infer that by testing if the file has changed in the meantime. E.g. when I execute `make` it two times in succession, it will execute the first time, but not the second time.

Comment: I had to remove the trailing colon, but otherwise, worked perfectly, thank you very much. Write this in an answer and I will mark it as the right answer. I never really thought about how $(FILES) would expand, but it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(subst source,target,$(FILES)): $(FILES)
```

expands to

```
target/a target/b target/c: source/a source/b source/c
```

which means that each single target depends on all files in `source`, probably not what you intended. Either a [static](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern) or an implicit rule can fix this, static rules are generally better as they are more specific:

```
$(subst source,target,$(FILES)): target/%: source/%
```